# Odoo 14 QWEB report page border

Tags: html, css, odoo, odoo-14, qweb

I need to generate a pdf report with a border all around the page.
I tried to add the border to the div "page" but it doesn't take the whole page, it is dynamic based on the height of the div.

```
<div class="page" style="border-radius: 25px; padding: 10px; border: 3px solid #0070c0;">
```

[image]

I want that the borders would cover the entire page and replicate to all pages.
Can you help me?